# rails omniauth and base uri view problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, omniauth

When I deploy my rails app to production I set: RailsBaseURI /my_app so that I can have:
mydomain.com/my_app as the location of my rails app.  I've setup omniauth as my provider for authenticating.  the problem is that when it goes to call my session controller's action of signup I get the following error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template /m_app/services/signup with 
{:handlers=>[:rjs, :rhtml, :rxml, :builder, :erb], :locale=>[:en, :en], 
:formats=>[:html]} in view paths
"/home/webadmin/mydomain.com/my_app/releases/20110621181033/app/views", 
"/home/webadmin/mydomain.com/my_app/releases/20110621181033", "/"):
          app/controllers/services_controller.rb:128:in `create'
```

Line 128 of services_controller looks like:

```
render signup_services_path
```

My routes for the services controller looks like:

```
  resources :services, :only => [:index, :create, :destroy] do
    collection do
      get 'signin'
      get 'signout'
      get 'signup'
      post 'newaccount'
      get 'failure'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Actually, looks like you might have a typo in the path to your view -- `Missing template /m_app/services/signup` should be `/my_app/services/signup`.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your entire controller, I can't be sure, but I recently encountered a similar problem with OmniAuth. Here are the two things that worked for me:

Description:

1. There is a virtual host for internalserver.com.
2. The virtual host has two apps deployed within it as follows:

   ```
   #/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
   <VirtualHost _default_:443>
       ServerName internalserver.com:443
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sites
       <Directory /var/www/html/sites>
           AllowOverride all
           Options -Multiviews
       </Directory>

       # Stable App
       <Directory /var/www/html/sites/stable>
           RailsBaseURI /stable
           RackBaseURI /stable
           Options -MultiViews
           RailsEnv production
       </Directory>

       # Beta App
       <Directory /var/www/html/sites/beta>
           RailsBaseURI /beta
           RackBaseURI /beta
           Options -MultiViews
           RailsEnv development
       </Directory>

       # SSLStuff
           ...
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. The output of `ls -al /var/www/html/sites`:

   ```
   drwxr-xr-x. 14 apache apache   4096 Feb  6 19:05 app
   drwxr-xr-x. 14 apache apache   4096 Feb  9 18:15 app_beta
   lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root   root       32 Feb  6 00:00 beta -> /var/www/html/sites/app_beta/public
   lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root   root       32 Feb  6 00:00 stable -> /var/www/html/sites/app/public
   ```

The two steps I had to take to configure OmniAuth to work correctly:

1. The `OmniAuth.config.full_host` setting must be set with the sub-directory:

   ```
   #config/initializers/omniauth.rb
   Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
       ...
   end

   # Add this line
   OmniAuth.config.full_host = "https://internalserver.com/beta"

   # You could also do something dynamic like:
   # OmniAuth.config.full_host = "#{Settings.host.base_url.gsub(/\/$/, '')}"
   ```
2. For some reason, the named routes did not work when setting up the signin/signout links. I had to hardcode `<a href="/auth/<my-provider>">Click here to log in</a>` instead of using `<%= link_to "Click here to log in", signin_path %>`. I don't know why that is, but you could try that.

Comment: thanks! my problems was not exactly like this one, but the `OmniAuth.config.full_host = "https://external.com"` line did the trick!